# How to load common bash scripts in packer

Tags: packer

How do you load another common script for a provisioner such as 
`. scripts/common/import.sh`

```
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "script": "scripts/scr.sh",
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `file` to upload the common script to `/tmp/common.sh`:

```
"provisioners": [
  {
    "type": "file",
    "source": "scripts/common.sh",
    "destination": "/tmp/common.sh"
  }
  {
    "type": "shell",
    "script": "scripts/scr.sh"
  }
],
```

EDIT: Updated the answer to actually answer the question.

Comment: and which one of them will be executed?

Comment: All, in order .

Comment: Rewrote my answer to actually answer the question.